# Завершение работы приложения

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, activity

Скажите, есть ли возможность командой полностью закрыть приложение, чтобы даже при долгом нажатии кнопки "домой", оно не высвечивалось в списке приложений? Командой `finish()` проблема не решается. Если нет, то как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на приложение в списке оно перенаправляло на `MainActivity`, а не на ту, в которой сработала команда `finish()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

В стандартной ситуации достаточно вызвать `finish()` - активити завершится. Описанный ниже случай нужно использовать только в крайних ситуациях. В мире андроида не принято вручную завершать процессы - всё это должна делать система по своему разумению.

```
//эмулируем нажатие на HOME, сворачивая приложение
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);

//в зависимости от версии оси намертво убиваем приложение
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
    finishAndRemoveTask();
} 
else 
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    {
        finishAffinity();
    } else
    {
        finish();
    }
}

//и контрольный в голову
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

Comment: Улыбнул "контрольный в голову" :D

Comment: в манифесте в теге Activity можно добавить - android:noHistory="true"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Есть пара вопросов:
1) Для полного завершения хватит и блок кода с `if`?
2) Разные вариации `finish` в этом блоке выполняют одно и тоже для разных версий?

Comment: @Ivan, я помню как долго выгугливал этот вариант кода. Попытки его сократить приводили к проблеммам на разных осях. Лучше оставить как есть и не пытаться оптимизировать)

Comment: Этот код уже растаскивают на цитаты как true way завершения приложения, если что-то не получается нормальным способом :) По-моему, не мешает какой-то дисклеймер дописать.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, что-то добавил) Если есть что дописать - правьте)