# Выход из Android приложения

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение состоящее из множества экранов. На каждом экране есть кнопка для перехода на активити с главным меню. Как сделать, чтобы после перехода по кнопке "Домой" из любого активити, переходило на главное активити, после чего с помощью нажатия на кнопку "back" телефона выйти из приложения, а не нажимать 100 раз на кнопку "back"  перелистывая все активити на которые зашел, чтобы выйти?

Comment: `Intent`'у "домой" добавьте флаги `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` | `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант можно переопределить в главной активити нажатие на кнопку назад и не завершать активити, а [эмулировать нажатие на `HOME` кнопку телефона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570758/17609). Так приложение свернётся, а не будет показывать предыдущие активити.

```
@Override  
public void onBackPressed()
    //эмулируем нажатие на HOME, сворачивая приложение
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

А вообще да, лучше изучить почему и как у вас активити в стеке остались и не допускать этого

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте этот код во все активности, кроме главной

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    //код для перехода к вашей главной активности
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

А чтобы при нажатии `Back` на главной активности происходил выход добавьте в нее

```
@Override  
public void onBackPressed()
    finish();
}
```

**НО**

Если при переходе на главную активность все другие не будут закрыты (`finish()`-нуты)  - будет не выход а возвращение на нее. Поэтому сделайте чтобы все ваши переходы на главную активность сопровождались кодом `finish()`

Советую почитать про жизненный цикл приложения

Comment: Спасибо, но я имел ввиду Button, который перекидывает на главное активити. А насчет кнопки Back, спасибо.

Comment: Что-то еще или вопрос решен?