# Завершение приложения при закрытии всех Activity

Tags: java, android, activity-life-cycle

После закрытия всех активностей (например, до конца пользователь нажал кнопку назад), то приложение все еще живет (Например, класс потомок от Application), как завершить все приложение, после закрытия всех активностей и без костылей?

Comment: Не нужно этого делать. В Android завершением приложений занимается система.

Comment: Вот ещё вариант очень жёсткого и не рекомендуемого завершения приложения: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570758/17609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внутри `onBackPressed` или там, где вы хотите завершить приложение, пишете:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
finish()
```

Хотя в комментарии правильно пишут. Нет смысла принудительно завершать приложение, потому что система сама этим занимается.

Comment: Вот это именно то, что мне нужно. Спасибо!