# Не закрывается приложение в Android 10

Tags: java, android

Я закрываю приложение так

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.exit)
                    .setMessage(R.string.exit_yes)
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            Main2Activity.super.onBackPressed();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
        }
```

Потом закрываю его соответственно из диспетчера (и оно как бы закрывается)
но потом снова появляется в диспетчере !

Так только на Android 10!!

Как исправить кто сталкивался ?

Comment: Не очень понятно насколько окончательно вам надо "закрыть" приложение, но может вот такой способ подойдёт: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570758/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб легендарный ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Работает на 10
как работает объяснить не могу!

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
                        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(homeIntent);
```