# Закрытие (или полный выход с уничтожением процесса) по кнопке

Tags: android, kotlin

```
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ДА"){_,_ ->
    //finish()
    //android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
    //System.exit(1)
}
```

Как правильно выйти (закрыть, убить) из приложения? На метод `finish()` Android Studio ругается. На две другие строчки — нет, но понять вышло ли приложение или произошел crash с ошибкой не могу, так как в logcat ошибки нет:

[image: демонстрация ошибки]

**MainActivity.kt:**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { ..........

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val btnExit: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnExit) as Button
        btnExit.setOnClickListener {
            this.exitSid()
        }
```

**MyFunctions.kt:**

```kotlin
fun Context.exitSid() {
    val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Выход из программы")
    alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.appicon)
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Закрыть программу?")
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ДА"){_,_ ->
        Toast.makeText(this,"Программа закрыта",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        //finishAndRemoveTask()
        //finishAffinity()
        //finish()
        //this@FirstFragment.finish
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
        System.exit(1)

    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128168/discussion-on-question-by-jurvrn-------).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Завершение работы приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570754/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [`finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) есть у активити, но не у контекста.

В программировании не получится написать что угодно и где угодно, и чтобы оно заработало.

Когда вы пишете `finish()` внутри вашей активити, то это эквивалентно:

```kotlin
this.finish()
```

Либо:

```kotlin
this@MainActivity.finish()
```

Если вы хотите вызвать `finish` где-то еще, вне активности, то нужно передать объект `activity`, над которым вы хотите вызвать этот метод. Это не особенность Андроид или языка Котлин, а исходит просто из здравого смысла.

Так что если хотите, чтобы в вашей экстеншен-функции можно было вызвать `finish`, переделайте ее ресивер с `Context` на `Activity`:

```kotlin
fun Activity.exitSid() {
    finish()
}
```

Без экстеншен-функции это выглядело бы так:

```kotlin
fun exitSid(activity: Activity) {
    activity.finish()
}
```

А еще советую [почитать](https://habr.com/ru/post/141201/) основы, если вы не  знали, что `Activity` это наследник `Context`.

Comment: завтра смогу попробовать. У меня перед выходом предварительный алерт. Изменение в коде Context на Activity не повлияет на алерт? Вот код в теории будет таким? - Статью прочел, в теории понятно. А на практике - мне ведь надо не текущее активити закрыть, а всю программу.  https://pl.kotl.in/OxBj9a7sM

Comment: Зачем вам "закрыть всю программу"? В Android SDK такого понятия нет. Если очень хочется выстрелить себе в ногу, пользуйтесь костылями из [другого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570754) вопроса. В Андроид можете закрыть либо активити, либо весь таск. Если не знакомы с понятием тасков, прочтите, например, [это](https://habr.com/ru/post/186434/).

Comment: _"При переходах между различными Activity пользователь всегда может вернуться на предыдущую, закрытую Activity при нажатии кнопки back на устройстве. "_ это и хочу избежать - из любого активити программа должна закрыться по кнопке, а не переходить по ранее открытым активити.

Comment: Для этого в Андроиде есть другие механизмы, почитайте про таски.

Comment: значит надо эмулировать нажатие кнопки "домой" ? но это уже совсем другой вопрос. Поэтому данный вопрос темы актуален - как завершить приложение полностью?

Comment: [Завершение работы приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570758)

Comment: _то в Android с Home совсем другая история. Home гарантированно даёт возможность выйти из приложения. Поэтому в целях безопасности сложно её отловить, если вообще возможно._ - поэтому вопрос по эмуляции отпадает. Надо убивать процесс.

Comment: вернулись к тому  с чего начали). Но часть кода `//эмулируем нажатие на HOME, сворачивая приложение` - противоречит безопасности андроид и не должно работать. Иначе мне бы этого хватило. Завтра попробую. Где ошибки смотреть? а то не понятно то ли приложение аварийно завершилось от неправильного кода, то ли закрылось

Comment: понять, что код работает не могу. Поэтому ответа-решения не буду писать, хотя в логах нет ошибок. Итог простой: В MainActivity.kt `this.exitSid()`, в MyFunc.kt `fun Activity.exitSid() {...    finish()...` Так как у меня одно активити с двумя фрагментами, то по кнопке которая располагается в основном активити и видна в обоих фрагментах программа "закрывается" (а может и вылетает).  Проверить наверно можно путем сохранения данных при повторном вызове